# Is it possible to upload setuid-set file to ftp-accessible directories?

Tags: linux, ftp, file-permissions, freebsd, setuid

Just curious, is it possible to upload files set with setuid permission to directories using ftp and retain its setuid permission?

Or does FTP always change the permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FTP Specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) doesn't provide a way to transmit file permission bits between systems. Which makes sense: FTP clients and servers run on a lot of different OSs with very different file permission semantics.

File permissions of uploaded files are part of the server's configuration.

Comment: Have to add a bit of historical trivia. The [original FTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc114.txt) mentions that FTP had already been implemented on the PDP-10 and a GE Multics system. Unix is not mentioned (only invented two years before) nor is Linux (Linus Thorvalds was 1 year old). We tend to think of Unix/Linux as the reference implementation of TCP/IP, but that was not always true.